# CentOs 7 & SELInux: User cant write in the Webroot of Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, selinux

My user can't add, modify or delete apache/php files without sudo.

My enviroment is:

- CentOS Linux release            7.2.1511
- SELinux status:                 enabled
- Current mode:                   enforcing
- Apache                          2.4.23

My user is already on the group of apache:

```
$ id
uid=1000(lmeza) gid=1000(lmeza) groups=1000(lmeza),10(wheel),48(apache) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

The Webroot of Apache already have the label **httpd_sys_content_t**

```
$ ls -Z /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. root   root   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 cgi-bin
drwxr-sr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 html
```

I have a directory with the label httpd_sys_rw_content_t but i can't write on him:

```
$ ls -lahZ /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 modules

$ touch /var/www/html/modules/abc.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/www/html/modules/abc.txt’: Permission denied
```

**Correct** Get file access control lists:

```
$ getfacl /var/www/html
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/html
# owner: apache
# group: apache
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:apache:rwx
group::r-x
group:apache:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:apache:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:apache:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with SELinux, it's just your plain old Unix permissions. See [here](http://serverfault.com/a/483310/126632) for a solution.

Comment: @michael-hampton I've updated my question with the result of getfacl. 
It says "group::r-x" and it should be "group::rwx" it is right?

Comment: I am certain Michael is correct.   That said; just for completeness sake, you would also want to include the output of `grep deni /var/log/audit/audit.log` if you suspect SELinux is denying something and assuming auditd is running.  If there were any denies, you would want to pass them to `audit2why` or `audit2allow` to better understand your options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to establish SELinux and ACL permissions that work on CentOs 7 are:

```
# Restablish the SELInux context:
sudo restorecon -Rv /var/www/html
# Change the owner of the webroot:
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
# Change basic permissiones:
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html
# Establish SELinux permissions:
sudo chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html
sudo chcon -Rt httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/modules
# Establish ACL permissions:
sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwx /var/www/html
sudo setfacl -R -m d:u:apache:rwx /var/www/html
sudo setfacl -R -m g:apache:rwx /var/www/html
sudo setfacl -R -m d:g:apache:rwx /var/www/html
```

The full script for Drupal 8 is on the next Gist:
https://gist.github.com/merolhack/854c3d371f31b21fb6cb538fe02a0444

Comment: This is a real life saver. I usually use all of them except the ACL ones, what are they for?