# Ressources not loading after setting up virtual host

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I managed to setup a virtual host, by using the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName entwicklung.hausfux
    ServerAdmin black@live.de
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/hausfux_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/hausfux_access.log common

    <Directory "/srv/www/vhosts/hausfux/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But now all urls include the path to the virtual host directory `/srv/www/vhosts/hausfux/` e.g.:

```
http://entwicklung.hausfux/srv/www/vhosts/hausfux/skin/frontend/venedor/default/css/styles-venedor.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

instead of:

http://entwicklung.hausfux/skin/frontend/venedor/default/css/styles-venedor.css

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your web application decides what its URLs look like. This has nothing to do with Apache.

Comment: I am using magento 1.9. You only have to enter the base url. I entered the vhost name `http://entwicklung.hausfux/` as base url as usual, which was always all I needed on WAMP when doing it with windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve it. The `/media` folder had not enough permission. I have set it to 777 now it works.

Solution found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/56352/66769).

Comment: The post you linked to has a serious error, which you have copied: It doesn't just make the folder writable by the apache user, it makes the folder writable by _everyone_. **DO NOT DO THIS.** It opens a massive security hole.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Thats incorrect, I tried other permissions too, it only works with 777. I also tried 774 without success. The owner is set to my ftp user and the group to wwwrun

Comment: Then you can fix either the owner or group, or use ACLs to make the permissions correct without having the security hole. I recommend [ACLs](https://serverfault.com/a/483310/126632).